# Set size of FieldLenField

Tags: python, scapy, network-protocols

I want a 1 byte `FieldLenField` to allow only 256 items in the corresponding `FieldListField`, how can I do it ?

```
from scapy import *

class Foo(Packet):
    name = "Foo"
    fields_desc = [
        ShortField("id", random.getrandbits(16)),
        FieldLenField("len", None, count_of="pld"),
        FieldListField("pld", None, IPField("", "0.0.0.0"), count_from=lambda pkt: pkt.len)
    ]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not add a check for > 255 items when building/reading this packet? You can throw an error if there's an unexpected number of items. Keep in mind Wireshark will also throw an error when it sees bytes in unexpected places (or marks it as a "malformed response").

Comment: @RossJacobs it would help to control the length of the varfield `pld`, but not the size of the lenfield `len`, so it doesn't really solve my problem. If I have at most 255 values, I don't want a 2 bytes lenfield as only 1 byte will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setting FieldLenField to 1 byte

You need to override the default length for `FieldLenField`, which is currently `H`. `H` is a [format character](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/struct.html#format-characters) from Python's struct library, which is an unsigned 2 bytes (0-65535). To force one-byte unsigned, use `B` instead:

```py
from scapy import *

class Foo(Packet):
    name = "Foo"
    fields_desc = [
        ShortField("id", random.getrandbits(16)),
        FieldLenField("len", 0, fmt="B", count_of="pld"),
        FieldListField("pld", None, IPField("", "0.0.0.0"), 
                       count_from=lambda pkt: pkt.len)
    ]

pkt = Foo()
print(bytes(pkt))
```

Running this, we'll get 2 random bytes for the ID and 1 byte for len, which looks like this:

`b'\x21\xea\x00'`

where the last byte is the default 0 we've set.

#### Verification

If instead we try to set the value of `len` to 300, which is outside the interval [0, 255], we'll get an error:

```py
pkt.len = 300
bytes(pkt)

...<traceback>
error: ubyte format requires 0 <= number <= 255
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to have any length desired, or is it only byte by byte?

Comment: The fmt var must be a valid struct format character

Comment: If that doesn’t answer your comment question, you may want to ask it as a question so you can provide more details